# I expected the program to produce a value , but it doesnt do so and exits with response code 0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Well, I have been doing the project euler questions today, and I saw problem 3 and started programming in objective C in it and it appears, its not functioning correctly. Below is my code, pls check and let me what and which error I am making. I am currently using Xcode and the purpose of the script is to return a inputted numbers largest prime factor.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {
    int number,primefactor, x;
    bool isPrime;
    NSLog (@"Please enter a number:");
    scanf ("%i", &number);
    for (primefactor = number;primefactor > 0;--primefactor)
    {
        if (number % primefactor == 0)
        {
            for (x = 2;x < primefactor;++x)
            {
                if (primefactor % x == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == TRUE)
        {
            NSLog (@"%i", primefactor);
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I expected the program to return a value and yet, it didnt do so and exited with an exit code of 0. You may checkout the output at http://tinypic.com/r/24d28hv/8

Comment: *"its not functioning correctly"* - that is a pretty bad problem description. What is your input data, what results do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: I am so sorry, but why was the question -1ed

Comment: Well, can someone hep me with a better algorithm now, that it is taking too much time

Comment: NO CODE, only algorithm

Comment: I have reverted your last edit because it changed the question entirely (and made it impossible for future readers to understand the given answers). Your initial question was why the above code does not work as expected. Asking for a better algorithm is a completely different question and should be posted separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is that `isPrime` must be set to `TRUE` each time before
the `primefactor` candidate is checked:

```
for (primefactor = number;primefactor > 0;--primefactor)
{
    if (number % primefactor == 0)
    {
        bool isPrime = TRUE; // <---- HERE
        for (x = 2;x < primefactor;++x)
        {
            if (primefactor % x == 0)
            {
                isPrime = FALSE;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == TRUE)
        {
            NSLog (@"%i", primefactor);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that to solve http://projecteuler.net/problem=3 for the number 600851475143
you have to use a larger data type. That number does not fit into a 32-bit integer.
You might also have to find a more efficient algorithm.)

Comment: I am so sorry, but well tried @MartinR, but the code still doesnt work, if you enter 25, still it doesnt return anything thats cause in Xcode all booleans are preinitialised to TRUE. Source: Programming in Objective C. But, still I tried that by initializing it to TRUE. The expected output in case of 25 would be 5

Comment: Plus, I gave the image you demanded and explained the error you were asking for

Comment: @user3486277: I have tested that code, and the output for 13195 is 29, and the output for 25 is 5, as expected. - Note that I moved also the `if (isPrime == TRUE)` part into the for-loop.

Comment: thats quite odd actually, I did the same as you said but it didnt work.

Comment: btw, plus one for your reputation. No, wait I cant do that, doing that needs 15 repo

Comment: @user3486277: Booleans are definitely not preinitialized to TRUE. And even if they were: When the next "primefactor" is tested you must *reset* it to TRUE, otherwise it will stay FALSE until the program ends. - I don't know how to help now. I have tested my code and I am pretty sure that it works. Did you copy/paste the complete code from my answer into your project?

Comment: Ya, when I am Copy/pasting your code, it works

Comment: But, well its been like a minute since its running producing no result

Comment: Can you provide any help with that ?

Comment: I meant, a better algorithm

Comment: @user3486277: I would have a look at the algorithms for the prime factorization of numbers ...

Comment: The code has now been refined

Comment: I believe my code is quite fast and efficient at the same time. It now skips division by even numbers and checks initially if number is even and it only finds one number, the answer, it doesnt even worry about other prime factors

Comment: @user3486277: Even if your algorithm checks 100000 possible prime factors in a second, it might take 600851475143 / 100000 / 3600 = 1669 hours !!

Comment: @user3486277: As I already said: Think of factorization into primes ...

Comment: what do u mean, I dont understand, @MartinR

Comment: @user3486277: How do you factor a number into primes? You check if your number is divisible by 3,5,7,... If you find a prime factor then you *divide* the number by that factor and continue with the smaller number ...

Comment: Hmmm....., let me think